# i18n-js translations not updating with additional translations in .yml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I have been reading about this for days, and nothing seems to be working. I have seen a lot of documentation of this issue, but none of the work arounds are working for me.
I have :

```
  Rails 5.0.1
  * sprockets (3.7.1)
  * sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
  * i18n (0.7.0)
  * i18n-js (3.0.0.rc15)
```

config/i18n-js.yml

```
translations:
- file: "app/assets/javascripts/application/i18n/translations.js"
  only: '*.js*'
```

config/application.rb

```
    config.middleware.use I18n::JS::Middleware
```

When I add new translations to the corresponding yml file, the i18n/translations.js does not update to include the new .yml translations.

For example, in en.yml:

```
en:
 form_error:
    tos_check: "You must agree to Lexody's Terms of Use to continue."
    choose_city: "Please select a city from the menu."
    cancel_reason: "Please provide a reason for cancelling."

$('.prompt').html('<p style="color:#e57373">' + I18n.t('form_error.cancel_reason') +'</p>');
```

returns: `[missing "en.form_error.cancel_reason" translation]`

I have tried:

Deleting translations.js and run `rake i18n:js:export`

`rake tmp:cache:clear`

`rake assets:precompile`

Does anyone have another solution I can try? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

After looking at the additional configuration files, this `config/i18n-js.yml` seems suspect:

```
translations:
- file: "app/assets/javascripts/application/i18n/translations.js"
  only: '*.js*'
```

According to the [export configuration](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js#export-configuration-for-translations) docs, the `only` key refers to the **translation keys** to be exported, not the filenames. So `'*.js*'` will match nothing, causing *no* translations to be exported.

Change this file to read:

```
translations:
- file: "app/assets/javascripts/application/i18n/translations.js"
  only: '*'
```

---

(Original answer below)

#### Working example

Here's a minimal, working example that produces expected behavior with the `i18n-js` gem:

```
#!/bin/bash
rails _5.0.1_ new .
echo "gem 'i18n-js', '3.0.0.rc15'" >> Gemfile
echo "  NEW_KEY: NEW_VALUE" >> config/locales/en.yml
bundle install
bundle exec rake i18n:js:export
grep -o '"NEW_KEY"' public/javascripts/translations.js
```

For me, running the above script outputs `"NEW_KEY"` on the last line, as expected (demonstrating that `NEW_KEY` is correctly added to `public/javascripts/translations.js` after running `i18n:js:export` in a fresh Rails installation), which means something else is going on in your local project.

#### Further investigation

In order to know what else exactly is going on, you'll have to further investigate exactly what configuration you've changed locally when compared to a fresh Rails installation.

(Note that the easiest way to do this is to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), such as a link to a GitHub repo that produces your issue exactly.)

- you say "the i18n/translations.js does not update to include the new .yml translations.", but the default path that gets updated is `public/javascripts/translations.js`. If you're using a non-standard path for your `translations.js` file, do you have additional configuration for this in `config/i18n-js.yml`? (If so, please share the entire contents of this file).
- Have you confirmed that the new translation doesn't show up in `translations.js` at all (e.g., using a `grep` command like the one above)? Or is it possible that the issue is related to the [asset pipeline](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js#rails-app-with-asset-pipeline) configuration instead?

Comment: Thanks for all the details! I added the relavent config files. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @gwalshington see update for the solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean `dev` or `prod` env. I had a similar problem in my `dev` env and I solved it by adding `config.middleware.use(I18n::JS::Middleware)` to `config/application.rb`. You can check it [here](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js#rails-app-without-asset-pipeline). Hope it helps.

Comment: it's all environments. I will add something new to the yml files, and that new translation does not come up. I tried what you suggested, but the translations are still missing :/

Answer (score 0):

In the `.yml` file, check for a colon after the language code.

Your example reads:

```
en
 form_error:
    cancel_reason: "Please provide a reason for cancelling."
```

Try:

```
en:
 form_error:
    cancel_reason: "Please provide a reason for cancelling."
```

I haven't tried exercising an example with this. However, the `.yml` files in the projects I have copies of all have colon after the language name. And it's just the sort of infuriating typo that might be invisible to someone close to it. Grr!

Comment: Thank you for the response! That is just a spelling error in my post, and not the reason new translations would be missing, but current ones are still there. Edited in question :)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have the English translation but is trying to access french locale instead.

Comment: That was just an example. The question says 'When I add new translations to the corresponding yml file, the i18n/translations.js does not update to include the new .yml translations.'   And even if I had the English translation, and it was looking for French, it would default to the English translation IF it could find it. Again... it is not there cause it isn't updating